# CentOS 7 - how to login as root

Tags: centos, password, shadow

I have a CentOS 7 image on my local machine that I want to allow login as root. This is going to be a system dedicated for testing.

I initially tried using rescue mode and added kernel param "systemd.unit=emergency.target" but it says root login is locked.

So I start /bin/bash instead. I see root in /etc/shadow is locked using "!!". So I run passwd root and assign it a password. However, I am still unable to login as root. It keeps telling me password incorrect (I'm sure password is correct). Is there somewhere else I overlooked?

I am logging in via console, not using SSH.

Comment: This is documented here: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/recover-root-passwd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you modified the filesystem in an emergency shell or from a rescue disk.  Your SELinux labels are probably wrong for /etc/shadow.  Easiest fix is to `touch /.autorelabel`  and reboot normally.  It will relabel the filesystem and reboot.

Comment: Just want to thank both you and @berndbausch for pointing me to the right direction, I have no idea autorelabel is a thing.